# i have mysql 8.0.2 installed on my ubuntu 16.04.can not open it through terminal. so what to do now?

Tags: mysql, root, password-recovery

root@biki:/home/welcome# mysql -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
.

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
mysql --user=user_name --password{=password} db_name
```

or

```
mysql -u user_name -p{password} db_name
```

using the mysql **admin** username and password, or the appropriate db_name's username/password, or your_own_username/password.

If you wish to login using the root username, you may have to add that info to the mysql authorized list of users... but of course... you're not normally logged into the root account... correct?